# How to load and run a container at run time from a running pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm working on a compute framework that will run on Google Container Engine (Kubernetes).

The desired behavior, is that users will provide a container to be executed (this is the user payload, we are ok doing this as the users are few and trusted). The user container will be uploaded to the registry beforehand.

When the framework runs, it will launch a number of workers (each on a pod, listening to a celery queue) and a master node will load a bunch of arguments to pass to the workers (trough celery/rabbitmq).

When a worker runs, it will perform 3 things (for each work item):

1. `SET UP`: The worker will copy files and configurations from google cloud storage and other places. The files will be placed in a pod's volume.
2. `EXECUTION`: The worker should download the user container from the registry and run it. I also want to capture `stdout` and `stderr` from the container's process, and if possible add a deadline (if the container hasn't completed execution within X seconds, halt). The user container will generate it's results as files in a volume directory.
3. `CLEAN UP and REPORTING`: The host pod will copy some artifacts generated by the user container back to google cloud. Other results will be reported to a proprietary application.

I want the framework to be invisible to the users (because we don't want to share credentials with them and prevent them from having any task-managing logic).

Since the host is a container itself, haven't found a good way to achieve this (pull and run a container within a script running in another container).

Is this possible to achieve in Kubernetes? Is there any documentation or projects doing anything similar? and, Are there any pitfalls with this approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so I'm understanding, you want a pod to launch another pod?

Comment: @Frap Not a pod, but to run a container (with user provided code) from within the original pod and wait for it to exit. A container (user) running inside a container (framework) in a pod.

Comment: That seems like a complete anti-pattern to me. Kubernetes is designed to abstract away the concept of individual containers. You may be able to do what you want with init containers and the new cron job resource, or possibly doing some docker in docker stuff, but I think you might want to reconsider what you're trying to do.

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/01/how-we-run-kubernetes-in-kubernetes-kubeception.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving it as follows:

First, I created a `job` defined as follows (snippet):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: item-001
spec: 
  template:
    metadata:
      name: item-xxx 
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: worker
        image: gcr.io/<something>/worker
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
          name: docker-socket-mount
        - mountPath: /workspace
          name: workspace 
      volumes:
        - name: docker-socket-mount
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: workspace 
          hostPath:
            path: /home/workspace
```

There are 2 mounts, the first `docker-socket-mount` mounts `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container, so I can use Docker from inside, and the second, it mounts a volume that will be shared between the host and the guest container `workspace`.

The `worker` runs a script similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IMAGE=gcr.io/some/guest/image

# ...

gsutil -m cp -r gs://some/files/I/need/* /workspace

# ...

export DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.23
gcloud docker -- pull ${IMAGE}
docker run -v /home/workspace:/workspace ${IMAGE} 

# ...
```

Having the docker socket available, it's good enough to install the docker client and call it normally. The trick was to mount the guest image from `/home/workspace`, as seen from the kubernetes node and not from the host image (`/workspace`). The files downloaded to `/workspace` are now also available on the guest container.

Finally, the `Dockerfile` looks similar to this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# ...

# Install Docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh

# Install Google Cloud SDK
ADD xxx.json /home/keys/xxx.json
RUN curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com > /tmp/gcloud.sh
RUN bash /tmp/gcloud.sh --disable-prompts --install-dir=/home/tools/
RUN /home/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth activate-service-account name@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=/home/keys/xxx.json
RUN /home/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config set project my-project

# ...
```